# ¿Cómo enviar a la base de datos de firebase el resultado de una votación sobre una notificación? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification

Estamos realizando un proyecto en el que queremos lanzar notificaciones que puedan ser votadas (¡hecho! :) y queremos enviar el resultado de la votación sobre la notificación a la base de datos.

Tecnologías aplicadas: **JavaScript** y **FireBase**

El resultado de la votación está guardado en una variable de manera global en el archivo del Service Worker, pero no consigo recuperarlo en otro (no estamos utilizando módulos) ni me permite trabajar con `firebase().database()` en el `sw.js`

¿Alguien tiene alguna pista?

Código:

La primera parte actúa sobre una notificación, recoge el estado de ánimo, y lo guarda en una variable (cuando pinchas sobre esa opción en la notificación)

```
function innerEvent(e) {
    currentUserID = e.notification.tag;
    const clickedNotification = e.notification;
    console.log(currentUserID);
    if (e.action === 'Happy') {
        dailyMood = e.action;
        clickedNotification.close();
    } else if (e.action === 'Sad') {
        dailyMood = e.action;
        clickedNotification.close();
    }
};

function saveDailyMood() {
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function getDataNotification(e) {
        innerEvent(e);
        getDataEvent(dailyMood);
        console.log(dailyMood);
     });
    return getDataEvent(dailyMood);
}

function getDataEvent(dailyMood) {
    return dailyMood;
}
saveDailyMood();`
```

y querría usar este método de firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref(`user: ${currentUserID}`).set({
        dailyMood: dailyMood
});
```

Pero constantemente me da como error que firebase no está definido... 
Firebase se inicializa en un archivo client.js y ServiceWorker en un archivo initServiceWorker.js (ambos en una carpeta src, que está dentro de otra public) y el archivo donde tengo las funciones descritas arriba están directamente en public... desde index.html(también en public) llamo a todos...